# I want to understand this trait syntax

Tags: rust

I want to understand this code.

```
pub trait Trait: balances::Trait {
    type Event: From<Event<Self>> + Into<<Self as system::Trait>::Event>;
}
```

Could you please explain in detail one word code at a time?

`pub trait Trait`  means, define trait named Trait?

`balances::Trait` what's this? Is this for `Trait`?

`type Event:`  ?

`From<Event<Self>>` ....?

`+ Into<<Self as system::Trait>::Event>` ....?

Comment: I suggest you start learning about "Trait" and "impl Trait" first, before moving into FRAME:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait.html
,
https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/impl_trait.html

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a trait called `Trait`, which will idiomatically be referred to in other places as `your_pallet_name::Trait`.

It descends from `balances::Trait`, which means that this functionality is dependent on the balances functionality and can make use of it.

The `Event` type would be fulfilled by the actual top-level `Event` type when the runtime is put together (and your pallet is combined with other pallets to produce an event type that encompasses events from all the pallets together). The bounds indicate that it's convertible `From` the local events declared by your pallet, and that it's convertible `Into` the low-level event type that actually gets placed in the event storage at the end of the block.